# get dbref from document in Mongo using Java

Tags: java, mongodb, dbref

I cannot get dbRef object from Mongo. In my entity package I have a `User` class with a `Parent` class inheriting.
Here is the `User` class:

```
public class User {

@Id
private ObjectId id;

@DBRef
private Account account;

private String name;

public String getId() {
    if (id != null) {
        return id.toStringMongod();
    }           

    return null;//no id
}

public void setId(ObjectId objectId) {
    this.id = objectId;
}

public Account getAccount() {
    return account;
}

public void setAccount(Account account) {
    this.account = account;
}
public String getLogin() {
    return login;
}

public void setLogin(String login) {
    this.login = login;
}
}
```

As you can see above, I am putting an object of `Account` here. 
My `Parent` class simply extends `User`:

```
@Document
public class Parent extends User {

@JsonProperty("is_activated")
private boolean isActivated;

public boolean isActivated() {
    return isActivated;
}

public void setActivated(boolean isActivated) {
    this.isActivated = isActivated;
}
}
```

Note: nothing magic with `isActivated`.

In my `ParentDaoImpl` class:

```
@Service
public class ParentDaoImpl extends AbstractDaoImpl implements ParentDao {

@Override
public Parent getParentByLogin(String login) {
    Query query = new Query(Criteria.where("login").is(login));
    return mongoOperations.findOne(query, Parent.class, "parents");
}
}
```

The problem is that if I call `getParentByLogin` method, it returns evertyning but `Account` field is null. Maybe `findOne` doesn't give dbRef inside. I think in relational Databases, there would be something like `join`.  I want my method to give me `account` field as well.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: You have actually set anything into the account field? If it returns null I guess it's...null. Not sure if the mongodb java driver automatically resolves the dbref. Maybe you need to add some Annotation (configuration) to autoload dbrefs.

Comment: I didn't mention `Account` class there. Creating Account before `getParentBylogin` is provided. I mean I first created account for the parent(I can get it in mongo shell or through my app as well), and then tried to get the whole parent

Comment: Do you use the pure mongodb java driver or some framework around it like Spring Data/morphia? @Service looks like Spring Data.
Maybe you should give a short example how you populate your database in the first place. Maybe there's the error.

Comment: I am using Spring. I was actually careful about testing that before I post here. Unfortunately, now I got it worked. I apologize for that! Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you try something like this.

```
....
@Field("fieldName")
@DBRef(collection = "mongoCollectionName")
private Account account;
....
```

Comment: thanks for the response. I tried it, no success. Still returning null, even though there is a specific account related to the parent object

Comment: First time I tried with the aid of your response seemed fail. But recently, I made it. Thank you very much!

Comment: when i add the @DBRef(collection = "mongoCollectionName") it says theres no method called collection